# FInd all numbers between 2 rang in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi i want to find all number between two rang like
2006 to 2010 : 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010
[image]

if any anyone know this please help thanks

Comment: Have you got ms365? If so, use `SEQUENCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have O365, you can use `SEQUENCE()`, as @JvdV stated in his comment to the OP. This seems to be the neater option, however, here is a version that will only use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and `COLUMN()` in case you don't have O365:

Assuming your "Begin Year" heading is in `A1`:

```
=IF((MIN($A2:$B2)+COLUMN()-3)>MAX($A2:$B2),"",MIN($A2:$B2)+COLUMN()-3)
```

This should be entered into `C2` and copied to across and down.